# DBIx::Class Get row from another table by ID

Tags: perl, dbix-class

In my project I have 3 tables: Artists, Albums and Tracks

**Result Artist:**

```
...
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
     'albums' => 'MYLIB::DB::Schema::Result::MyDir::Album',
     { 'foreign.artist_id' => 'self.id', },
);
...
```

**Result Album:**

```
...
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
     'artist' => 'MYLIB::DB::Schema::Result::Artist',
     { 'foreign.id' => 'self.artist_id', },
  );

__PACKAGE__->has_many(
     'tracks' => 'MYLIB::DB::Schema::Result::MyDir::Track',
     { 'foreign.album_id' => 'self.id', },
 );
...
```

**Result Track:**

```
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to(
    'album' => 'MYLIB::DB::Schema::Result::MyDir::Album',
    { 'foreign.id' => 'self.album_id', },
);
```

Now I have a object `$artist` and I want to get a Track by ID.

Query Example:
`SELECT * FROM Tracks WHERE track_id = $x`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to generate the SQL that you give us, then the fact that you have an artist object is irrelevant. Just get a track resultset and run `find()` on that.

```
my $track_rs = $schema->resultset('Track');
my $track = $track_rs->find($track_id);
```

If, for some reason, you don't have a schema object, then you can get that from your artist object.

```
my $schema = $artist->result_source->schema;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the track is on an album by your `$artist`. The query can be done by a join over the three tables. See [DBIx::Class::Manual::Joining](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aJoining).

Here is an untested example.

```
my $tracks = $artist->search_related(
    { 
        id => $my_track_id,
    },
    { 
        join => { albums => 'tracks' },
    }
);
```

If your track is not necessarily by $artist, then it propably makes more sense to query `tracks`directly.